# Representation of $T^*\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, symplectic-geometry, tangent-bundle

Can anyone explain the following representation of the dual space of $\mathbb{S}^2(ie. T^*\mathbb{S}^2)$?

$$T^∗\mathbb{S}^2=\lbrace(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^3×\mathbb{R}^3:|u|= 1,\ 〈u, v〉= 0\rbrace$$

In a book, they give this representation but for me, this looks like representation for $T\mathbb{S}^2$. Maybe I am wrong. Please explain my mistake.

Thanks, Advance.

Comment: They are identifying $v\in\mathbb{R^3}$ with the functional $\langle \cdot,v\rangle$ in the dual of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yea but why it is not $T\mathbb{S}^2$?

Comment: It is, also, if you just look at $v$ as just the vector $v$.

Comment: Is it mean that both the spaces are same?

Comment: Every vector bundle on a manifold is isomorphic to its dual.

Comment: The two spaces are not the same. The tangent bundle has as elements tangent vector while the cotangent bundle does not. In fact, the set of pairs of vectors you describe in your question is neither the tangent bundle not the cotangent bundle! It is isomorphic as a bundle to both, tho.

Comment: Not the same, the nature of the elements is different. That is why I said 'identifying'. If you want, for the co-tangent $T^∗\mathbb{S}^2=\lbrace(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^3×(\mathbb{R}^3)^*: |u|= 1,\ \langle u,v\rangle= 0\rbrace$ would have been more precise, where $\langle u,v\rangle$ is denoting $v(u)$.

Comment: I meant same in the sense isomorphic. Then what is the necessity to study them with the different name?

Comment: Because the isomorphism between them depends on a choice, just like the isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its dual.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks...

Comment: Making a choice to identifying them is not the reason. Given two congruent triangles you also need to make a choice on how to identify them, yet there is no need to give them different names. It is because you need to allude to their nature when applying them. You use one to define notions like vector fields, the other to define forms. The way they operate are different and often times are used simultaneously. So, you need to name them.